# How to prevent click propagation when we have a parent anchor limk which has a button as one of children

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

When I click on the Link parent it fires the click on the button as well, I want both events to be separated.

```
<Link className="product-item__link" to={`/products/${product.category}/${product.id}`} >
    <div className='product-item'>
        {/*I have here other elements*/}
        <button className="product-item__btn" onClick={() => addToCart(product)}>Add to cart</button>
     </div>
</Link>
```

Comment: Putting a `<button>` inside an `<a>` is not valid HTML.

Comment: event.preventDefault() will stop the propagation

Comment: @Pointy Yeah you are right, but I found myself pushed to do that to get the wanted result.
Is there any other alternative?

Comment: @Pointy I refactored the code to be like this :

<div className='product-item'>
    <Link to={`/products/${product.category}/${product.id}`}>
        {/*I have here other elements*/}
    </Link>
    <button  onClick={() => addToCart(product)}>Add to cart</button>
 </div>

Comment: Well I'm sure you've got a complicated thing to deal with, but to me the problem is not so much that it's "invalid", but that it is kind-of confusing for the user. Those problems can be challenging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add stop propagation in the function call of button click

```
<Link className="product-item__link" to={`/products/${product.category}/${product.id}`} >
    <div className='product-item'>
        {/*I have here other elements*/}
        <button className="product-item__btn" onClick={(e) => addToCart(e, product)}>Add to cart</button>
     </div>
</Link>
```

change function definition

```
const addToCart = (e, product) => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      //rest of the code...
}
```